# Natural Text Processing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, text-processing

I am currently writing on a habit-tracking iOS application. Therefore I'd love to add natural text processing in order to create the intervals the habits should be logged.

Examples would be:

- Hit the gym 3 times a week
- Read a book every day for 30 minutes
- Go out for a walk every Monday and Saturday

I did some research and found that Apple has some API to do text processing.
Unfortunately I am not quite sure if it offers anything I need to build this parser/processor and how to achieve it. I had a look at `NSDataDetector` but with the help of this I only achieved to parse date and time:

```
func process(string:String)  -> [NSDate] {
    var matches:[NSDate] = []
    do {
    let dataDetector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Date.rawValue)
    dataDetector.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count), usingBlock: { (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, flag : NSMatchingFlags, ump : UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
            if let result = result {
                if let resultDate = result.date {
                    matches.append(resultDate)
                }
            }
        })
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
    return matches
}
```

I hope to get some advice on how to extend my use of Apple's API in order to parse the above examples or for some other solution to achieve my goal.

Comment: Well you could use NSRegularExpression for your needs... It looks just like the NSDataDetector Syntax, but you can define your own pattern?

Comment: maybe NSLinguisticTagger can help you. It is explained in this NSHipster article: [link](http://nshipster.com/nslinguistictagger/)

Comment: yeah thanks the NSLinguisticTagger looks very promising. If I can build something to achieve my goal I'll let you all know here.

Comment: also found some natural language parsers for recurring events in ruby and python which will hopefully help me to achieve something similar in swift: https://github.com/yb66/tickle and https://github.com/kvh/recurrent